# How does apache choose the executable for a cgi script?

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I've been doing some experiments, and trying to understand the results.

In my apache conf I have:

```
balter@balterbox:/etc/apache2$ cat sites-enabled/000-default.conf
.  
.  
.  

<Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .pl .php .py .p1 .p2 .sh
</Directory>
```

In my /var/www/html I have three files:

**hello.py**

```
balter@balterbox:/var/www/html$ cat hello.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("<html><body><h1>Hello from python</h1></body></html>")
```

**hello.p1**

```
balter@balterbox:/var/www/html$ cat hello.p1
#!/usr/bin/env python

print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("<html><body><h1>Hello from python</h1></body></html>")
```

**hello.p2**

```
balter@balterbox:/var/www/html$ cat hello.p2
#!/home/balter/conda/bin/python

print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print("<html><body><h1>Hello from python</h1></body></html>")
```

This is what happens when I `curl` them:

```
balter@balterbox:/var/www/html$ curl localhost/hello.py
<html><body><h1>Hello from python</h1></body></html>
balter@balterbox:/var/www/html$ curl localhost/hello.p1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
 webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
balter@balterbox:/var/www/html$ curl localhost/hello.p2
<html><body><h1>Hello from python</h1></body></html>
```

The error in the apache log is:

> [Thu May 24 06:50:00.681713 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 8481] [client 127.0.0.1:35306] malformed header from script 'hello.p1': Bad header: ()

I'm assuming the bad header is because the script actually ignored the shebang and ran under the default system python.

```
balter@balterbox:/var/log/apache2$ /usr/bin/python -V
Python 2.7.15rc1
balter@balterbox:/var/log/apache2$ /usr/bin/env python -V
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
balter@balterbox:/var/log/apache2$ which python
/home/balter/conda/bin/python
```

Is there a simple way to make apache just use `/usr/bin/env *****`?

Comment: Can the user your webserver runs at actually access and execute binaries installed in your home directory? `sudo -u nobody /var/www/html/hello.p1`

Comment: @HBruijn -- Yes. That command runs appropriately. I have everything in `/var/www` set with group=www-data, and I added myself to the group. So whether root or I own the file, www-data still has `rwx`.